# Google Apps Script - Read spreadsheet data, loop, and write data back

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for some help on looping through a set of data in a spreadsheet by row, then write the value in the first cell to a new sheet followed by each cell value across the rows.

Here is a link to a sample set of data.  [Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-ZC12r3kabwF7IoagVp6iy4bqGJnUczggpq-JPrKzI0/edit?usp=sharing)

Sheet1 on the above spreadsheet shows the raw data.  I want to read in that data and write it to sheet two (2) so that it looks like what is on sheet 2 of the above link.

Here is the current code I have but it writes all data into a single column.

```
function myfunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = 
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      var iava_value = (data[i][0]);
      var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow();           
      sheet2.getRange(lastRow +1, +1).setValue(data[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {

Comment: Replace [0] with [j] inside the loop. To be var iava_value = (data[i][j]);            Then set sheet2 like:  sheet2.getRange(lastRow +1,+1).setValue(data[i][0]);

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions..  Didn't get quite what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working version of what I was trying to do.

```
function transpose() {
  var sheet = 
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = 
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  
  var myRA = new Array(2); 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
    //GET IAVA No
  var iava_no = data[i][0];    

    for (var j = 1; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      var plugin_id = (data[i][j]);      

    if(plugin_id === ""  || plugin_id =="n"  || plugin_id == "a"){        
     break;        
    }
    else
    {
    Logger.log(plugin_id);
    var lastrow = sheet2.getLastRow();      
    sheet2.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1).setValue(data[i][0]);        
    sheet2.getRange(lastrow + 1, 2).setValue(data[i][j]);
   }
 }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will write the data across in first available row

```
function myfunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');  
  var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var colCounter = 1
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      var iava_value = (data[i][0]);       
      sheet2.getRange(lastRow +1, colCounter).setValue(data[i][j]);
      colCounter++;
 }
 };
 }
```

However, note the above code is the not the most efficient way to process/write the data. A lot of overhead = time to writing values individually to the sheets.

This is a much better approach

```
function myfunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');  
  var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var reArrangeData = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  {
    reArrangeData = reArrangeData.concat(data[i])
    // concat the arrays end over end to get 1D array
 }
 sheet2.getRange(lastRow +1, 1, 1,   reArrangeData.length).setValues([reArrangeData]);
 };
 }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks but it putting across a single row.  I was looking for the end result to be two columns.  The first column contains the first cell in each row, the second column contains the values of each cell to the right of the far left cell on each row.