# How to write the result of a loop into a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below code sends out emails including a table in the body with data rows and header in html. It also attaches the same data into an xlsx and pdf file. Some like it in pdf, some like it in the body of the email, some like it in xlsx so ...

I have 2 issue's with below code:

The result of the loop, table/rows, should be written to a google sheet (Export). This sheet will then be attached as PDF & XLSX to the email sent.

Currently the "Export" sheet is already attached but it's "empty" as the data is not yet written to the Export Sheet, that is the question how to?

I tried to add already the lines "xlsxTable += data[row][col];" in the code to catch the data but I don't think it's the proper way to do so.

Second issue is that sometimes the attachment (xlsx) is not "correctly" formatted and contains the following words: "This file might be un". (Google preview) When downloading the xlsx it's saying, file format not correct ... but the strange thing is, when sending out to 3 different emails 2 of them are OK, 1 is not, sometimes all are OK. Maybe this is timing issue and should include a pause.

Any help is welcome, Thanks!

Below code uses google sheets, with 4 sheet inside: Data, Emails, Parameters, Export.

Data Sheet

```
ID    Name      Amount   Date
1000  Company    500.23  01/01/2019
2000  Company    500.23  01/01/2019
1000  Company    500.23  01/01/2019
3000  Company    500.23  01/01/2019
1000  Company    500.23  01/01/2019
2000  Company    500.23  01/01/2019
```

Emails Sheet

```
ID      To  Cc Bcc FirstName Subject Language BodyStart BodyEnd Sent SentDate
1000    Company1@email.com
2000    Company2@email.com
3000    Company3@email.com
```

Parameters Sheet contains just the ReplyTo & ReplyToName

Actual Code

```
function Statements_Attachments() {

  //This section specifies the sheet and some fixed variables.

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
    var dataRange = ss.getSheetByName("Data").getDataRange();
    var emailRange = ss.getSheetByName("Emails").getDataRange();
    var param = ss.getSheetByName("Parameters");
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var nameData = emailRange.getValues();
    var lastCol = dataRange.getLastColumn();
    var lastRow = emailRange.getLastRow();
    var replyEmail = param.getRange("B2").getValue();
    var replyName = param.getRange("B3").getValue();
    var sentRange = ss.getSheetByName("Emails");
    var startRow = 1;
    var sent = "Y";

    var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ssID = ssA.getId();
    var ssName = ssA.getName();
    var sheetName = "Export";  //Fill in Sheet Name you want to Email
    var shID = getSheetID(sheetName); //Get Sheet ID of Sheet Name

  //This section below starts the loop comparing the key between the 2 sheets.

  for (var i = 1; i < nameData.length; i++) {

    var rows = nameData[i];
    var emailAddress = rows[2]; 
    var keyID = rows[0];
    var ccMail = rows[3];
    var bccMail = rows[4];
    var bodyStart = rows[8]; 
    var bodyEnd = rows[9];
    var keyName = rows[1];
    var subject = rows[6] ;
    var emailSent = rows[10];
    var xlsxTable = "";         //Variable used to collect the Data for pasting in "Export Sheet"
    var exportTable = "";       //Variable used to paste Data in "Export Sheet"
    var htmlTable = "";         // HTML body Table created to paste in Email
    var htmlMessage = "";
    var preTable = '<!DOCTYPE html><html>' + bodyStart ;
    var postTable = '</html>';   

    for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
      if (row == 0){
        for (col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (col == 0) {
              htmlTable += '<tr><th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#558EDB">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
              xlsxTable += data[row][col];
          } else
          if (col == lastCol - 1) {
              htmlTable += '<th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#558EDB">' + data[row][col] + '</th></tr>';
              xlsxTable += data[row][col];
          } else {
              htmlTable += '<th style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;background-color:#558EDB">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
              xlsxTable += data[row][col];
          }
        }      
      }
      else if (data[row][0] == keyID) {
        for (col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (col == 0) {
              htmlTable += '<tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
              xlsxTable += data[row][col];
          } else
          if (col == lastCol - 1) {
              htmlTable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td></tr>';
              xlsxTable += data[row][col];
          } else
          if (col == 6) {
              htmlTable += '<td align="right" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
              xlsxTable += data[row][col];
          } else
          if (col == 20 || col == 21) {
              htmlTable += '<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + Utilities.formatDate(data[row][col], "GMT", "dd-mm-yyyy") + '</td>';
              xlsxTable += data[row][col];
          } else {
              htmlTable += '<td align="right" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
              xlsxTable += data[row][col];
          }
        }  
      }
    }


    //The section below closes the table in the body and constructs the complete body.

      htmlTable += '</tbody></table>';
      htmlMessage = preTable + htmlTable + bodyEnd + postTable;


    //The section below should paste the Data into the Export Sheet, to be used as basis for the xlsx & pdf attachment to the email.

      exportTable = xlsxTable;
    //How to write the result to the Export Sheet in columns and rows.

    //The section below sets the variables for the Attachment.

      var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ ssID +"&gid="+ shID;
      var urlPdf = url + "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";

      var paramsP = {
        method      : "get",
        headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
        muteHttpExceptions: true
      };

      var paramsX = {
        method      : "get",
        headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
        muteHttpExceptions: true
      };


      var blobPdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlPdf, paramsP).getBlob();
      var blobP = blobPdf.setName(sheetName + ".pdf");

      var blobXlsx = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, paramsX).getBlob();
      var blobX = blobXlsx.setName(sheetName + ".xlsx");


    //The section below retrieves alias email address to send as

      var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();// Log the aliases for this Gmail account.
      var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases(); // Gets the alias from account
      Logger.log(aliases);  // Logs the alias


    // The section below sends the actual emails

       if (emailAddress != "" && emailSent != sent){   //If next email address needs to be different add: && nextEmail != emailAddress
         if (aliases.length > 0){  // Prevents sending duplicates

         GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '', {
           htmlBody: htmlMessage,
           from : aliases[1],
           cc : ccMail,
           bcc : bccMail,
           replyTo : replyEmail,
           name : replyName,
           attachments : [blobP, blobX],
         });

    // The section below puts a "Y" next to the row already processed.

          sentRange.getRange(startRow + i, 11).setValue(sent);
          sentRange.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(new Date ());    

          //Utilities.sleep(1000);
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted

          }   
        }  
     }
  }


function getSheetID(name){
 var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(name)
 var sheetID = sheetName.getSheetId().toString() 
 return sheetID
}
```

Comment: 1 issue per question. Please reduce your code to a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your specific issue. For example, you can help yourself by refactoring your code into multiple functions instead of a large monolith, as you can then identify which parts work correctly, and which parts do not. As for writing to a Google Sheet, read the associated official guide on Apps Script official documentation.

Comment: Posted code works and does not give any errors, the only problem is that I don't know how to write the data into a sheet like mentioned above. I did check [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) but have trouble translating the example to the above solution.

Comment: The solution is then to work at examples until you understand how reading & writing cell values works, and only **then** do it in your specific, complicated, real-world use case. Trying to go straight from simple-code-A to complicated-code-B when you don't understand what is happening in A is not a good plan.

Comment: Welcome FDF. I second @tehhowch's comments. You have a VERY sophisticated script, yet somehow you have missed out on learning the basics of google sheets scripts - how to read and write data. There are literally dozens of topics on this very question; this is as good as any other [Google Apps Script - Read spreadsheet data, loop, and write data back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239985/). I strongly advise - play with some data until you understand the commands and mechanics of read and write, then apply those principles to your scenario.